# Compiler keeps spitting "Class Interface or Enum Expected" can anyone spot what I've done wrong?

Tags: java, syntax, enums

It appears there is a problem with my main, but I can't figure it out. I'm new to java and am pretty tired. Using Netbeans 7.3.1 if that's any help

```
package Retro;

import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;

main class Retro {

    @SuppressWarnings("ConvertToTryWithResources")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            FileReader readfile = new FileReader("blah.txt");
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(readfile);

            String str;
            while ((str = bf.readLine()) != null) {

                out.println(str + "\n");

            }

            bf.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            out.println("File not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `main` in `main class Retro`?

Comment: I didn't intend to use a main class. I originally just used "class" but netbeans didn't want that. I am an absolute programming noob and just need help

Comment: Have you gone through a [java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)?

Comment: You've also got a class with the same name as the package. While that's legal, it's really not a good idea. Just removing the word `main` before `class` makes it valid Java code though.

Comment: I'm just playing around with the buffered reader to get the hang of it. Because I'm appalingly bad and cannot get the hang of it.

Comment: You don't need to catch the IOException at all, this is not only simpler but likely to be more accurate than "File not found"

Comment: Really, but "computer says no". Netbeans is not having it.

Comment: Replace `main class` with `public class` If this doesn't help give us the actual error

Comment: Aaah, fixed it, just prematurely posted my problem! cheers anyway guys

Answer (score 8):

The `main class Retro` part will not compile.

`main` is not a Java keyword.

Just remove it.

You only need a `static` method called `main`, with a `String[]` or varargs `String...` signature and returning `void` to have an executable class.

Minor note: package names should be lowercased.

Answer (score 0):

```
package Retro;

import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Retro {

@SuppressWarnings("ConvertToTryWithResources")
public static void main (String[] args){

    try {

    FileReader readfile = new FileReader ("blah.txt");
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader (readfile);

    String str;
    while ((str = bf.readLine()) != null){

        out.println(str + "\n");

                                          }

    bf.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        out.println("File not found");
                            }
                                        }
                    }
```

You put main before class and the compiler does not know what "main" is.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the package declaration (first line) and the keyword main, then I think you will find that it compiles AND runs. Something like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Retro {

@SuppressWarnings("ConvertToTryWithResources")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        FileReader readfile = new FileReader("blah.txt");
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(readfile);

        String str;
        while ((str = bf.readLine()) != null) {

            out.println(str + "\n");

        }

        bf.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        out.println("File not found");
    }
}
}
```